# What's the main purpose of using cache-first strategies in Workbox?

Tags: service-worker, workbox

Reading Workbox [strategies documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies), and I found I can't imagine the situation using "cache-first" strategies in Workbox.

There is "Stale-While-Revalidate" strategies which uses cache first, and in background, updates cache file through Network. If you change the target file, it is useful because when access next time, the App uses latest file which last time cached. If you don't have any changes, there is no disadvantage, I think.

What is the main purpose using "cache-first" strategies in Workbox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

(This answer isn't specific to Workbox, though Workbox makes it easier to use these strategies, instead of "rolling them by hand.")

I'd recommend using a cache-first strategy when you're sure that the content at a given URL won't change. If you're confident of that, then the extra network request made in the stale-while-revalidate strategy is just a waste—why bother with that overhead?

The scenarios in which you should have the highest confidence that the content at a URL won't change is if the URL contains some explicit versioning information (e.g. `https://example.com/librbaries/v1.0.0/index.js`) or a hash of the underlying contents (e.g. `https://example.com/libraries/index.abcd1234.js`).

It can sometimes make sense to use a cache-first strategy when a resource might update, but your users are not likely to "care" about the update, and the cost of retrieving that the update is high. For example, you could argue that using a cache-first strategy for the images used in the body of an article is a reasonable tradeoff, even if the image URLs aren't explicitly versioned. Seeing an out of date image might not be the worst thing, and you would not force your users to download a potentially large image during the revalidation step.